# How to extract all weights from LSTM cell in vanila Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I am train LSTM network

```
cell_fw = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(HIDDEN_SIZE)
cell_bw = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(HIDDEN_SIZE)

rnn_outputs, final_state_fw, final_state_bw = tf.contrib.rnn.static_bidirectional_rnn(
    cell_fw=cell_fw,
    cell_bw=cell_bw,
    inputs=rnn_inputs,
    dtype=tf.float32
)
```

Further, I am try to save it coefficients:

```
d = {}
with tf.Session() as sess:
    # train code ...
    variables_names =[v.name for v in tf.global_variables()]
    values = sess.run(variables_names)
    for k,v in zip(variables_names, values):
        d[k] = v
```

Dictionary d have only 2 objects from each LSTM cell:

```
[(k,v.shape) for (k,v) in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x:x[0])]
[('bidirectional_rnn/bw/basic_lstm_cell/biases:0', (1024,)),
 ('bidirectional_rnn/bw/basic_lstm_cell/weights:0', (272, 1024)),
 ('bidirectional_rnn/fw/basic_lstm_cell/biases:0', (1024,)),
 ('bidirectional_rnn/fw/basic_lstm_cell/weights:0', (272, 1024)),
 ('char_embedding:0', (70, 16)),
 ('softmax_biases:0', (5068,)),
 ('softmax_weights:0', (5068, 512))]
```

I'm puzzled. Each LSTM cell should contain up to 4 trainable layers, or not? If so, how to get all weights from LSTM-cell??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the 4 weights (and biases) of a LSTM cell are stored as a single tensor, where slices along the second axis correspond to the different kind of weights (in gate, forget gate, ecc)

For instance, I guess that in your case the value of `HIDDEN_SIZE` is 256

To access the different parts, you should slice the tensors along the axis of length 1024 (but I don't know in which order the different kind of weights are stored...)

Comment: Ohh, It's true. Thanks, I can relax.